# How can I combine a list of Line[]'s into one continuous Line?

Tags: graphics

I have a huge list of Lines. Take this one as an example:

```
linelist1 = {Line[{{0.150, 0.099}, {0.151, 0.095}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.104}, {0.150, 0.099}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.095}, {0.152, 0.090}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.108}, {0.149, 0.104}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.114}, {0.149, 0.108}}], Line[{{0.152, 0.090}, {0.154, 0.087}}], Line[{{0.154, 0.087}, {0.157, 0.083}}], Line[{{0.157, 0.083}, {0.159, 0.080}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.119}, {0.149, 0.114}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.125}, {0.149, 0.119}}], Line[{{0.150, 0.132}, {0.150, 0.130}}], Line[{{0.150, 0.130}, {0.149, 0.125}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.136}, {0.150, 0.132}}], Line[{{0.162, 0.079}, {0.167, 0.076}}], Line[{{0.159, 0.080}, {0.162, 0.079}}], Line[{{0.167, 0.076}, {0.171, 0.076}}], Line[{{0.171, 0.076}, {0.179, 0.075}}], Line[{{0.152, 0.144}, {0.152, 0.141}}], Line[{{0.152, 0.141}, {0.151, 0.136}}], Line[{{0.154, 0.153}, {0.153, 0.148}}], Line[{{0.153, 0.148}, {0.152, 0.144}}], Line[{{0.154, 0.170}, {0.154, 0.153}}], Line[{{0.179, 0.075}, {0.184, 0.076}}], Line[{{0.184, 0.076}, {0.195, 0.079}}], Line[{{0.195, 0.079}, {0.202, 0.082}}], Line[{{0.202, 0.082}, {0.217, 0.089}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.182}, {0.151, 0.180}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.180}, {0.154, 0.170}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.193}, {0.151, 0.182}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.195}, {0.149, 0.193}}], Line[{{0.148, 0.204}, {0.149, 0.195}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.208}, {0.147, 0.206}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.219}, {0.147, 0.208}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.206}, {0.148, 0.204}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.220}, {0.147, 0.219}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.223}, {0.147, 0.220}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.235}, {0.147, 0.234}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.248}, {0.147, 0.235}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.234}, {0.147, 0.223}}], Line[{{0.217, 0.089}, {0.226, 0.094}}], Line[{{0.237, 0.102}, {0.246, 0.107}}], Line[{{0.236, 0.101}, {0.237, 0.102}}], Line[{{0.226, 0.094}, {0.236, 0.101}}], Line[{{0.246, 0.107}, {0.258, 0.115}}], Line[{{0.270, 0.126}, {0.283, 0.135}}], Line[{{0.258, 0.115}, {0.270, 0.126}}], Line[{{0.283, 0.135}, {0.297, 0.147}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.249}, {0.147, 0.248}}], Line[{{0.147, 0.251}, {0.147, 0.249}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.263}, {0.147, 0.251}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.265}, {0.149, 0.263}}], Line[{{0.149, 0.266}, {0.149, 0.265}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.278}, {0.149, 0.266}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.280}, {0.151, 0.278}}], Line[{{0.151, 0.281}, {0.151, 0.280}}], Line[{{0.154, 0.295}, {0.151, 0.281}}], Line[{{0.154, 0.296}, {0.154, 0.295}}], Line[{{0.154, 0.297}, {0.154, 0.296}}], Line[{{0.157, 0.310}, {0.154, 0.297}}], Line[{{0.158, 0.311}, {0.157, 0.310}}], Line[{{0.158, 0.312}, {0.158, 0.311}}], Line[{{0.162, 0.326}, {0.158, 0.312}}], Line[{{0.162, 0.327}, {0.162, 0.326}}], Line[{{0.167, 0.342}, {0.162, 0.327}}], Line[{{0.297, 0.147}, {0.312, 0.161}}], Line[{{0.312, 0.161}, {0.327, 0.175}}], Line[{{0.168, 0.343}, {0.167, 0.342}}], Line[{{0.167, 0.342}, {0.167, 0.342}}], Line[{{0.174, 0.358}, {0.173, 0.357}}], Line[{{0.173, 0.357}, {0.168, 0.343}}], Line[{{0.180, 0.372}, {0.174, 0.358}}], Line[{{0.180, 0.372}, {0.180, 0.372}}], Line[{{0.188, 0.386}, {0.180, 0.372}}], Line[{{0.188, 0.386}, {0.188, 0.386}}], Line[{{0.196, 0.399}, {0.188, 0.386}}], Line[{{0.196, 0.399}, {0.196, 0.399}}], Line[{{0.205, 0.412}, {0.196, 0.399}}], Line[{{0.205, 0.412}, {0.205, 0.412}}], Line[{{0.214, 0.423}, {0.205, 0.412}}], Line[{{0.215, 0.424}, {0.214, 0.423}}], Line[{{0.214, 0.423}, {0.214, 0.423}}], Line[{{0.224, 0.434}, {0.224, 0.434}}], Line[{{0.225, 0.435}, {0.224, 0.434}}], Line[{{0.224, 0.434}, {0.215, 0.424}}], Line[{{0.236, 0.445}, {0.235, 0.444}}], Line[{{0.235, 0.444}, {0.234, 0.444}}], Line[{{0.234, 0.444}, {0.225, 0.435}}], Line[{{0.245, 0.452}, {0.236, 0.445}}], Line[{{0.247, 0.454}, {0.246, 0.453}}], Line[{{0.246, 0.453}, {0.245, 0.452}}], Line[{{0.257, 0.460}, {0.247, 0.454}}], Line[{{0.258, 0.462}, {0.257, 0.461}}], Line[{{0.257, 0.461}, {0.257, 0.460}}], Line[{{0.271, 0.469}, {0.270, 0.469}}], Line[{{0.270, 0.469}, {0.269, 0.468}}], Line[{{0.269, 0.468}, {0.258, 0.462}}], Line[{{0.282, 0.475}, {0.281, 0.474}}], Line[{{0.283, 0.475}, {0.282, 0.475}}], Line[{{0.292, 0.480}, {0.283, 0.475}}], Line[{{0.281, 0.474}, {0.271, 0.469}}], Line[{{0.296, 0.481}, {0.295, 0.481}}], Line[{{0.293, 0.480}, {0.292, 0.480}}], Line[{{0.295, 0.481}, {0.293, 0.480}}], Line[{{0.307, 0.485}, {0.305, 0.485}}], Line[{{0.308, 0.485}, {0.307, 0.485}}], Line[{{0.305, 0.485}, {0.296, 0.481}}], Line[{{0.320, 0.489}, {0.318, 0.489}}], Line[{{0.330, 0.492}, {0.320, 0.489}}], Line[{{0.318, 0.489}, {0.308, 0.485}}], Line[{{0.327, 0.175}, {0.343, 0.190}}], Line[{{0.343, 0.190}, {0.358, 0.207}}], Line[{{0.358, 0.207}, {0.375, 0.224}}], Line[{{0.391, 0.241}, {0.405, 0.260}}], Line[{{0.405, 0.260}, {0.421, 0.278}}], Line[{{0.375, 0.224}, {0.391, 0.241}}], Line[{{0.421, 0.278}, {0.436, 0.296}}], Line[{{0.436, 0.296}, {0.448, 0.315}}], Line[{{0.448, 0.315}, {0.459, 0.331}}], Line[{{0.459, 0.331}, {0.471, 0.348}}], Line[{{0.332, 0.492}, {0.331, 0.492}}], Line[{{0.331, 0.492}, {0.330, 0.492}}], Line[{{0.343, 0.494}, {0.332, 0.492}}], Line[{{0.354, 0.495}, {0.344, 0.494}}], Line[{{0.344, 0.494}, {0.343, 0.494}}], Line[{{0.355, 0.496}, {0.354, 0.495}}], Line[{{0.356, 0.495}, {0.355, 0.496}}], Line[{{0.471, 0.348}, {0.480, 0.364}}], Line[{{0.486, 0.376}, {0.494, 0.390}}], Line[{{0.480, 0.364}, {0.486, 0.376}}], Line[{{0.494, 0.390}, {0.500, 0.403}}], Line[{{0.367, 0.496}, {0.366, 0.496}}], Line[{{0.366, 0.496}, {0.356, 0.495}}], Line[{{0.377, 0.496}, {0.377, 0.496}}], Line[{{0.387, 0.495}, {0.377, 0.496}}], Line[{{0.377, 0.496}, {0.367, 0.496}}], Line[{{0.387, 0.495}, {0.387, 0.495}}], Line[{{0.396, 0.493}, {0.387, 0.495}}], Line[{{0.397, 0.493}, {0.396, 0.493}}], Line[{{0.405, 0.490}, {0.397, 0.493}}], Line[{{0.405, 0.490}, {0.405, 0.490}}], Line[{{0.413, 0.487}, {0.405, 0.490}}], Line[{{0.413, 0.487}, {0.413, 0.487}}], Line[{{0.500, 0.403}, {0.502, 0.413}}], Line[{{0.504, 0.420}, {0.507, 0.429}}], Line[{{0.502, 0.413}, {0.504, 0.420}}], Line[{{0.427, 0.478}, {0.420, 0.483}}], Line[{{0.420, 0.483}, {0.413, 0.487}}], Line[{{0.432, 0.472}, {0.427, 0.478}}], Line[{{0.433, 0.472}, {0.432, 0.472}}], Line[{{0.437, 0.465}, {0.433, 0.472}}], Line[{{0.507, 0.429}, {0.507, 0.436}}], Line[{{0.507, 0.436}, {0.504, 0.444}}], Line[{{0.477, 0.451}, {0.473, 0.450}}], Line[{{0.473, 0.450}, {0.437, 0.465}}], Line[{{0.504, 0.444}, {0.502, 0.448}}], Line[{{0.483, 0.452}, {0.477, 0.451}}], Line[{{0.502, 0.448}, {0.499, 0.451}}], Line[{{0.489, 0.453}, {0.483, 0.452}}], Line[{{0.499, 0.451}, {0.493, 0.452}}], Line[{{0.493, 0.452}, {0.489, 0.453}}]};
```

Here's what it looks like graphically:

```
Graphics@linelist1
```

[image]

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to make this line dashed. However, if I do it right now, the line segments are all so small that the dashing doesn't work for most of it:

```
Graphics@{Dashed, linelist1}
```

[image]

Here's a semi-solution I've tried:

```
Boundary2SingleLine[inBd_] := (
  pts = Flatten[inBd[[All, 1]], 1];
  orderedpts = First@FindCurvePath@pts;
  Return@Line[pts[[orderedpts]]];
  )
Graphics@{Dashed, Boundary2SingleLine@linelist1}
```

[image]

Lookin good! However, if I do it with this set of lines:

```
linelist2={Line[{{0.217, 0.171}, {0.217, 0.166}}], Line[{{0.217, 0.166}, {0.218, 0.161}}], Line[{{0.218, 0.176}, {0.217, 0.171}}], Line[{{0.218, 0.177}, {0.218, 0.176}}], Line[{{0.220, 0.157}, {0.220, 0.156}}], Line[{{0.218, 0.161}, {0.220, 0.157}}], Line[{{0.218, 0.178}, {0.218, 0.177}}], Line[{{0.219, 0.182}, {0.218, 0.178}}], Line[{{0.219, 0.183}, {0.219, 0.182}}], Line[{{0.220, 0.186}, {0.219, 0.184}}], Line[{{0.219, 0.184}, {0.219, 0.183}}], Line[{{0.220, 0.189}, {0.220, 0.186}}], Line[{{0.222, 0.196}, {0.221, 0.192}}], Line[{{0.221, 0.192}, {0.220, 0.189}}], Line[{{0.220, 0.156}, {0.223, 0.152}}], Line[{{0.223, 0.152}, {0.228, 0.147}}], Line[{{0.234, 0.143}, {0.240, 0.141}}], Line[{{0.228, 0.147}, {0.234, 0.143}}], Line[{{0.223, 0.199}, {0.222, 0.196}}], Line[{{0.224, 0.202}, {0.223, 0.199}}], Line[{{0.225, 0.206}, {0.224, 0.202}}], Line[{{0.227, 0.213}, {0.226, 0.209}}], Line[{{0.229, 0.217}, {0.227, 0.213}}], Line[{{0.226, 0.209}, {0.225, 0.206}}], Line[{{0.230, 0.220}, {0.229, 0.217}}], Line[{{0.231, 0.224}, {0.230, 0.220}}], Line[{{0.232, 0.227}, {0.231, 0.224}}], Line[{{0.234, 0.234}, {0.232, 0.227}}], Line[{{0.235, 0.237}, {0.234, 0.234}}], Line[{{0.237, 0.243}, {0.235, 0.237}}], Line[{{0.240, 0.141}, {0.243, 0.140}}], Line[{{0.243, 0.140}, {0.250, 0.138}}], Line[{{0.250, 0.138}, {0.254, 0.138}}], Line[{{0.254, 0.138}, {0.263, 0.138}}], Line[{{0.263, 0.138}, {0.268, 0.138}}], Line[{{0.268, 0.138}, {0.278, 0.138}}], Line[{{0.239, 0.246}, {0.237, 0.243}}], Line[{{0.239, 0.248}, {0.239, 0.246}}], Line[{{0.240, 0.251}, {0.239, 0.248}}], Line[{{0.243, 0.259}, {0.242, 0.256}}], Line[{{0.245, 0.263}, {0.243, 0.259}}], Line[{{0.242, 0.256}, {0.240, 0.251}}], Line[{{0.248, 0.269}, {0.247, 0.267}}], Line[{{0.250, 0.273}, {0.248, 0.269}}], Line[{{0.247, 0.267}, {0.245, 0.263}}], Line[{{0.253, 0.281}, {0.252, 0.278}}], Line[{{0.252, 0.278}, {0.250, 0.273}}], Line[{{0.240, 0.335}, {0.253, 0.281}}], Line[{{0.278, 0.138}, {0.285, 0.140}}], Line[{{0.285, 0.140}, {0.296, 0.141}}], Line[{{0.296, 0.141}, {0.304, 0.144}}], Line[{{0.304, 0.144}, {0.316, 0.147}}], Line[{{0.316, 0.147}, {0.326, 0.150}}], Line[{{0.326, 0.150}, {0.338, 0.155}}], Line[{{0.338, 0.155}, {0.350, 0.160}}], Line[{{0.239, 0.336}, {0.240, 0.335}}], Line[{{0.239, 0.336}, {0.239, 0.336}}], Line[{{0.240, 0.337}, {0.239, 0.336}}], Line[{{0.242, 0.338}, {0.240, 0.337}}], Line[{{0.244, 0.339}, {0.242, 0.338}}], Line[{{0.248, 0.340}, {0.244, 0.339}}], Line[{{0.252, 0.341}, {0.248, 0.340}}], Line[{{0.257, 0.342}, {0.256, 0.342}}], Line[{{0.256, 0.342}, {0.252, 0.341}}], Line[{{0.262, 0.343}, {0.257, 0.342}}], Line[{{0.266, 0.343}, {0.262, 0.343}}], Line[{{0.295, 0.363}, {0.266, 0.343}}], Line[{{0.297, 0.366}, {0.295, 0.363}}], Line[{{0.299, 0.369}, {0.297, 0.366}}], Line[{{0.301, 0.373}, {0.299, 0.369}}], Line[{{0.303, 0.377}, {0.301, 0.373}}], Line[{{0.305, 0.381}, {0.303, 0.377}}], Line[{{0.307, 0.384}, {0.305, 0.381}}], Line[{{0.309, 0.389}, {0.307, 0.384}}], Line[{{0.311, 0.393}, {0.309, 0.389}}], Line[{{0.314, 0.397}, {0.311, 0.393}}], Line[{{0.316, 0.400}, {0.314, 0.397}}], Line[{{0.318, 0.404}, {0.316, 0.400}}], Line[{{0.321, 0.408}, {0.318, 0.404}}], Line[{{0.323, 0.412}, {0.321, 0.408}}], Line[{{0.325, 0.416}, {0.323, 0.412}}], Line[{{0.328, 0.420}, {0.325, 0.416}}], Line[{{0.330, 0.424}, {0.328, 0.420}}], Line[{{0.333, 0.428}, {0.330, 0.424}}], Line[{{0.335, 0.431}, {0.333, 0.428}}], Line[{{0.338, 0.436}, {0.335, 0.431}}], Line[{{0.340, 0.439}, {0.338, 0.436}}], Line[{{0.350, 0.160}, {0.362, 0.166}}], Line[{{0.362, 0.166}, {0.375, 0.172}}], Line[{{0.375, 0.172}, {0.386, 0.179}}], Line[{{0.386, 0.179}, {0.389, 0.181}}], Line[{{0.401, 0.188}, {0.411, 0.195}}], Line[{{0.389, 0.181}, {0.401, 0.188}}], Line[{{0.411, 0.195}, {0.415, 0.198}}], Line[{{0.415, 0.198}, {0.426, 0.205}}], Line[{{0.426, 0.205}, {0.440, 0.216}}], Line[{{0.440, 0.216}, {0.449, 0.224}}], Line[{{0.449, 0.224}, {0.454, 0.228}}], Line[{{0.454, 0.228}, {0.463, 0.236}}], Line[{{0.463, 0.236}, {0.471, 0.245}}], Line[{{0.475, 0.249}, {0.483, 0.257}}], Line[{{0.471, 0.245}, {0.475, 0.249}}], Line[{{0.483, 0.257}, {0.516, 0.272}}], Line[{{0.516, 0.272}, {0.524, 0.272}}], Line[{{0.550, 0.275}, {0.573, 0.280}}], Line[{{0.573, 0.280}, {0.586, 0.282}}], Line[{{0.524, 0.272}, {0.550, 0.275}}], Line[{{0.586, 0.282}, {0.610, 0.287}}], Line[{{0.610, 0.287}, {0.624, 0.295}}], Line[{{0.624, 0.295}, {0.636, 0.300}}], Line[{{0.636, 0.300}, {0.641, 0.309}}], Line[{{0.641, 0.309}, {0.640, 0.317}}], Line[{{0.640, 0.317}, {0.633, 0.326}}], Line[{{0.633, 0.326}, {0.619, 0.333}}], Line[{{0.619, 0.333}, {0.600, 0.341}}], Line[{{0.600, 0.341}, {0.583, 0.347}}], Line[{{0.343, 0.443}, {0.340, 0.439}}], Line[{{0.345, 0.446}, {0.343, 0.443}}], Line[{{0.348, 0.450}, {0.345, 0.446}}], Line[{{0.350, 0.454}, {0.348, 0.450}}], Line[{{0.353, 0.457}, {0.350, 0.454}}], Line[{{0.355, 0.460}, {0.353, 0.457}}], Line[{{0.358, 0.464}, {0.355, 0.460}}], Line[{{0.360, 0.466}, {0.358, 0.464}}], Line[{{0.363, 0.470}, {0.360, 0.466}}], Line[{{0.583, 0.347}, {0.541, 0.385}}], Line[{{0.541, 0.385}, {0.540, 0.392}}], Line[{{0.540, 0.392}, {0.539, 0.401}}], Line[{{0.368, 0.475}, {0.366, 0.473}}], Line[{{0.370, 0.478}, {0.368, 0.475}}], Line[{{0.366, 0.473}, {0.363, 0.470}}], Line[{{0.373, 0.481}, {0.370, 0.478}}], Line[{{0.375, 0.483}, {0.373, 0.481}}], Line[{{0.378, 0.485}, {0.375, 0.483}}], Line[{{0.381, 0.488}, {0.378, 0.485}}], Line[{{0.383, 0.490}, {0.381, 0.488}}], Line[{{0.385, 0.491}, {0.383, 0.490}}], Line[{{0.388, 0.494}, {0.385, 0.491}}], Line[{{0.392, 0.497}, {0.390, 0.495}}], Line[{{0.390, 0.495}, {0.388, 0.494}}], Line[{{0.395, 0.498}, {0.392, 0.497}}], Line[{{0.397, 0.500}, {0.395, 0.498}}], Line[{{0.399, 0.500}, {0.397, 0.500}}], Line[{{0.402, 0.501}, {0.399, 0.500}}], Line[{{0.539, 0.401}, {0.538, 0.407}}], Line[{{0.538, 0.407}, {0.536, 0.414}}], Line[{{0.536, 0.414}, {0.534, 0.420}}], Line[{{0.534, 0.420}, {0.532, 0.426}}], Line[{{0.532, 0.426}, {0.529, 0.432}}], Line[{{0.529, 0.432}, {0.526, 0.437}}], Line[{{0.526, 0.437}, {0.522, 0.443}}], Line[{{0.522, 0.443}, {0.519, 0.447}}], Line[{{0.519, 0.447}, {0.515, 0.452}}], Line[{{0.404, 0.502}, {0.402, 0.501}}], Line[{{0.406, 0.503}, {0.404, 0.502}}], Line[{{0.409, 0.503}, {0.406, 0.503}}], Line[{{0.411, 0.504}, {0.409, 0.503}}], Line[{{0.415, 0.504}, {0.411, 0.504}}], Line[{{0.421, 0.503}, {0.417, 0.504}}], Line[{{0.417, 0.504}, {0.415, 0.504}}], Line[{{0.423, 0.503}, {0.421, 0.503}}], Line[{{0.427, 0.501}, {0.423, 0.503}}], Line[{{0.428, 0.500}, {0.427, 0.501}}], Line[{{0.432, 0.498}, {0.428, 0.500}}], Line[{{0.515, 0.452}, {0.511, 0.455}}], Line[{{0.506, 0.459}, {0.502, 0.462}}], Line[{{0.511, 0.455}, {0.506, 0.459}}], Line[{{0.502, 0.462}, {0.497, 0.465}}], Line[{{0.433, 0.496}, {0.432, 0.498}}], Line[{{0.438, 0.492}, {0.437, 0.493}}], Line[{{0.437, 0.493}, {0.433, 0.496}}], Line[{{0.442, 0.488}, {0.438, 0.492}}], Line[{{0.493, 0.467}, {0.487, 0.470}}], Line[{{0.497, 0.465}, {0.493, 0.467}}], Line[{{0.487, 0.470}, {0.481, 0.472}}], Line[{{0.481, 0.472}, {0.477, 0.473}}], Line[{{0.470, 0.474}, {0.467, 0.475}}], Line[{{0.477, 0.473}, {0.470, 0.474}}], Line[{{0.467, 0.475}, {0.442, 0.488}}]}
```

It fails and only gets part of it:

```
Graphics@{Red, linelist2, Thickness -> .008, Black, Dashed, 
  Boundary2SingleLine@linelist2}
```

[image]

I figured out that for some reason FindCurvePaths is returning 2 lists in this case:

```
pts = Flatten[linelist2[[All, 1]], 1];
fcp = FindCurvePath@pts
Graphics@{Red, Line[pts[[fcp[[1]]]]], Blue, Line[pts[[fcp[[2]]]]]}
```

[image]

At this point I could manually finagle a way to attach these two lists, but I really have no guarantee it'll work generally, and I'm guessing this is an unnecessarily complicated solution anyway.

What's an easier way of doing this?

edit: Thank you for any advice. However, please show a solution **working with the second example set of lines**, as I already have a solution that works with the first.

edit: Here is @Michael E2's solution, which works on the second example:

```
Boundary2SingleLine[inBd_] := (
  gr = Graph[inBd /. Line[List[v__]] :> UndirectedEdge[v]];
  cycle = First@FindHamiltonianCycle[gr, 1];
  Return@Line[Append[cycle[[All, 1]], cycle[[-1, 2]]]];
  )
Graphics@{Dashing[.01], Boundary2SingleLine@linelist2}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you edit your post in such a way that makes it easy to get to the information that is needed to help.

Comment: @user21, sorry if it isn't clear, but what do you mean? The 2nd example? If so, I tried to include it in the main body but the input area said I reached the character limit.

Comment: You put a huge list of line in the text that you are not really interested in but the one you are interested in a link. In other words the not important data is more prominent that the important one.

Comment: @user21 alright, I think it's clearly explained if someone reads the whole post, but I'll change it. I can't have the full list for both, so do you think it would be better to make it so the full list is the 2nd one, and the 1st one is a link?

Comment: Why include the first example at all? And why have you copied one of the answers into the question?

Comment: @SimonWoods Because the usual protocol is to include any attempt you've made, and the first example illustrates that my attempt worked partially, but was not complete. As for copying the answer into the question, I've seen many people do that for answered questions.

Comment: In my opinion it would be sufficient just to state that `Boundary2SingleLine` works fine when `FindCurvePath` returns a single list. If you want to show the details then yes, I think you should put the working data in the link and the problem data in the post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a graph-based solution:

```
gr = Graph[linelist1 /. Line[List[v__]] :> UndirectedEdge[v]];
cycle = First@FindHamiltonianCycle[gr, 1];
Graphics[{Dashing[0.01], Line[Append[cycle[[All, 1]], cycle[[-1, 2]]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent, this works great on the 2nd example!

Answer (score 6):

The goal here is to turn the collection of `Line` objects into a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, and then extract the boundary from that region. This is similar to user21's solution, but a bit more robust for this application.

```
mr = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[linelist2];
MeshPrimitives[mr, 2] /. Polygon[a__] :> Line[a] // 
 Graphics[{Dashing[0.01], #}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, but the point of my post is that this doesn't work for my 2nd example. My first attempt at a solution does this already.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that looks good. Unfortunately I already chose an answer, thank you though!

Comment: @YungHummmma You're free to change your selection, if you think this is better than mine. It's close, and in a tie, one tends to prefer one's own children, so to speak. :)  This is also why some advise waiting a while before accepting, to see what answers come in. (+1, Jason.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. I wanted to point out that there are other ways to show approval of an answer than accepting, lol. I find it interesting that the graph path solution works where the FindCurvePath fails.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think I may have actually found a way in which yours fails, but for now it's working for me so I'll stick with it. (when I did the same shape, but with fewer points, I think, something broke.)

Answer (score 6):

```
linelist1 = {Line[{{0.15042300130733277`, 
      0.09918669845167598`}, {0.15124668865085406`, 0.09522452324491057`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14961629841942972`, 0.10444571885174352`}, {0.15042300130733277`, 
      0.09918669845167598`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15124668865085406`, 0.09522452324491057`}, {0.15296330904994523`, 
      0.09071834061461313`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14933067532583966`, 0.10873463230613303`}, {0.14961629841942972`, 
      0.10444571885174352`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1492065391252379`, 0.11459136282769972`}, {0.14933067532583966`, 
      0.10873463230613303`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15296330904994523`, 0.09071834061461313`}, {0.15443233429278366`, 
      0.08720754178169458`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15443233429278366`, 0.08720754178169458`}, {0.15738657618834503`, 
      0.0837116800119704`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15738657618834503`, 0.0837116800119704`}, {0.1596507357294199`, 
      0.08081800622081214`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14938185651096897`, 0.11910808435898695`}, {0.1492065391252379`, 
      0.11459136282769972`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14978835086914977`, 0.1254736636010152`}, {0.14938185651096897`, 
      0.11910808435898695`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15077460730814868`, 0.1327981842766949`}, {0.15036790182308324`, 
      0.13013455437855134`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15036790182308324`, 0.13013455437855134`}, {0.14978835086914977`, 
      0.1254736636010152`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15120855329817068`, 0.13696037633048153`}, {0.15077460730814868`, 
      0.1327981842766949`}}], 
   Line[{{0.16277911871721887`, 0.07929367135576196`}, {0.16756504304577993`, 
      0.07669208018087739`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1596507357294199`, 0.08081800622081214`}, {0.16277911871721887`, 
      0.07929367135576196`}}], 
   Line[{{0.16756504304577993`, 0.07669208018087739`}, {0.17179084853507678`, 
      0.07624695124973005`}}], 
   Line[{{0.17179084853507678`, 0.07624695124973005`}, {0.17906280098426666`, 
      0.07576450311212397`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15257273308627697`, 0.14470958676131765`}, {0.15214869088284963`, 
      0.14169046682959874`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15214869088284963`, 0.14169046682959874`}, {0.15120855329817068`, 
      0.13696037633048153`}}], 
   Line[{{0.154380363176796`, 0.15329508718925586`}, {0.15336715187177208`, 
      0.14894978414339125`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15336715187177208`, 0.14894978414339125`}, {0.15257273308627697`, 
      0.14470958676131765`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15408201484170664`, 0.17090212421388687`}, {0.154380363176796`, 
      0.15329508718925586`}}], 
   Line[{{0.17906280098426666`, 0.07576450311212397`}, {0.1846655098267246`, 
      0.07675733142107073`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1846655098267246`, 0.07675733142107073`}, {0.19526513101961043`, 
      0.07935442585321775`}}], 
   Line[{{0.19526513101961043`, 0.07935442585321775`}, {0.2025793721147758`, 
      0.08225275130107908`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2025793721147758`, 0.08225275130107908`}, {0.2174515369686099`, 
      0.0892027606755095`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15130771769953516`, 0.18272337857024754`}, {0.15175791747769907`, 
      0.1805607558081054`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15175791747769907`, 0.1805607558081054`}, {0.15408201484170664`, 
      0.17090212421388687`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14947523641765`, 0.19324727078363216`}, {0.15130771769953516`, 
      0.18272337857024754`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14922075255141615`, 0.195421957699875`}, {0.14947523641765`, 
      0.19324727078363216`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14830703464564116`, 0.20491305790082923`}, {0.14922075255141615`, 
      0.195421957699875`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14786378115799406`, 0.20890778773289803`}, {0.14791166732629607`, 
      0.20675668855532706`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1473023145442782`, 0.21917015209603855`}, {0.14786378115799406`, 
      0.20890778773289803`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14791166732629607`, 0.20675668855532706`}, {0.14830703464564116`, 
      0.20491305790082923`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1471112448868429`, 0.22098660364789832`}, {0.1473023145442782`, 
      0.21917015209603855`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14727721615276837`, 0.22307805371953965`}, {0.1471112448868429`, 
      0.22098660364789832`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1471140525731194`, 0.23582182314046962`}, {0.14709509899938097`, 
      0.23406594386910806`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14783588435291467`, 0.24801241612439603`}, {0.1471140525731194`, 
      0.23582182314046962`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14709509899938097`, 0.23406594386910806`}, {0.14727721615276837`, 
      0.22307805371953965`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2174515369686099`, 0.0892027606755095`}, {0.22682413867491788`, 
      0.09457182622878016`}}], 
   Line[{{0.23712928145996623`, 0.10232063183487138`}, {0.2468063966900775`, 
      0.10735408035037859`}}], 
   Line[{{0.23617311839755725`, 0.10167498697856284`}, {0.23712928145996623`, 
      0.10232063183487138`}}], 
   Line[{{0.22682413867491788`, 0.09457182622878016`}, {0.23617311839755725`, 
      0.10167498697856284`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2468063966900775`, 0.10735408035037859`}, {0.258487721590078`, 
      0.1157776125601875`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2708808482807588`, 0.12670886782426`}, {0.28387897498993575`, 
      0.13571165906064925`}}], 
   Line[{{0.258487721590078`, 0.1157776125601875`}, {0.2708808482807588`, 
      0.12670886782426`}}], 
   Line[{{0.28387897498993575`, 0.13571165906064925`}, {0.2978272217864588`, 
      0.14759488720466138`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1477234246451498`, 0.24947273784932386`}, {0.14783588435291467`, 
      0.24801241612439603`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1479541145674177`, 0.2511362254380753`}, {0.1477234246451498`, 
      0.24947273784932386`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1491240645508071`, 0.26387991264561694`}, {0.1479541145674177`, 
      0.2511362254380753`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14921751200149097`, 0.2652532987421324`}, {0.1491240645508071`, 
      0.26387991264561694`}}], 
   Line[{{0.14965754343046883`, 0.2667953281098005`}, {0.14921751200149097`, 
      0.2652532987421324`}}], 
   Line[{{0.151331525973231`, 0.2788746216617924`}, {0.14965754343046883`, 
      0.2667953281098005`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1513023469154561`, 0.28000225496294356`}, {0.151331525973231`, 
      0.2788746216617924`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15159808750593176`, 0.28126407977451784`}, {0.1513023469154561`, 
      0.28000225496294356`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1542183286126348`, 0.2951998224290116`}, {0.15159808750593176`, 
      0.28126407977451784`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1543844511422373`, 0.29622903636555487`}, {0.1542183286126348`, 
      0.2951998224290116`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15487515594649698`, 0.2973588777162937`}, {0.1543844511422373`, 
      0.29622903636555487`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1579674954611141`, 0.3106502784721332`}, {0.15487515594649698`, 
      0.2973588777162937`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15801884123013382`, 0.31149526756373586`}, {0.1579674954611141`, 
      0.3106502784721332`}}], 
   Line[{{0.15837231170577926`, 0.3124103567537063`}, {0.15801884123013382`, 
      0.31149526756373586`}}], 
   Line[{{0.16249412038258731`, 0.3268594270632616`}, {0.15837231170577926`, 
      0.3124103567537063`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1627258634053209`, 0.32761076950461077`}, {0.16249412038258731`, 
      0.3268594270632616`}}], 
   Line[{{0.1677923104797096`, 0.3421155216709148`}, {0.1627258634053209`, 
      0.32761076950461077`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2978272217864588`, 0.14759488720466138`}, {0.3120103725148076`, 
      0.16185946995643472`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3120103725148076`, 0.16185946995643472`}, {0.32775672771374703`, 
      0.17512244347152398`}}], 
   Line[{{0.16831982916051622`, 0.3434042241910501`}, {0.16791854046841395`, 
      0.3427532989898076`}}], 
   Line[{{0.16791854046841395`, 0.3427532989898076`}, {0.1677923104797096`, 
      0.3421155216709148`}}], 
   Line[{{0.17421155114809514`, 0.3581968200459465`}, {0.17392151465705788`, 
      0.35763372336909505`}}], 
   Line[{{0.17392151465705788`, 0.35763372336909505`}, {0.16831982916051622`, 
      0.3434042241910501`}}], 
   Line[{{0.18069422094150786`, 0.37205702305025484`}, {0.17421155114809514`, 
      0.3581968200459465`}}], 
   Line[{{0.180891236025593`, 0.37258053248480366`}, {0.18069422094150786`, 
      0.37205702305025484`}}], 
   Line[{{0.18830785455803709`, 0.38637151726676766`}, {0.180891236025593`, 
      0.37258053248480366`}}], 
   Line[{{0.18865265276787174`, 0.3868486426773692`}, {0.18830785455803709`, 
      0.38637151726676766`}}], 
   Line[{{0.19640017190085496`, 0.3994058587164615`}, {0.18865265276787174`, 
      0.3868486426773692`}}], 
   Line[{{0.19666833626667307`, 0.3999132604697406`}, {0.19640017190085496`, 
      0.3994058587164615`}}], 
   Line[{{0.20531029788487257`, 0.41211763157731013`}, {0.19666833626667307`, 
      0.3999132604697406`}}], 
   Line[{{0.20571216030393039`, 0.4126101422556851`}, {0.20531029788487257`, 
      0.41211763157731013`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2145020546238386`, 0.4233429398459504`}, {0.20571216030393039`, 
      0.4126101422556851`}}], 
   Line[{{0.21537048933945666`, 0.42440920138360355`}, {0.2148469636279404`, 
      0.42392452797297386`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2148469636279404`, 0.42392452797297386`}, {0.2145020546238386`, 
      0.4233429398459504`}}], 
   Line[{{0.224937909314532`, 0.4347906814830722`}, {0.22447106274957196`, 
      0.43419502129876153`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2255708635091629`, 0.4352755122957541`}, {0.224937909314532`, 
      0.4347906814830722`}}], 
   Line[{{0.22447106274957196`, 0.43419502129876153`}, {0.21537048933945666`, 
      0.42440920138360355`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2362387193659058`, 0.44519046171637694`}, {0.23550854177430175`, 
      0.44469711425577`}}], 
   Line[{{0.23550854177430175`, 0.44469711425577`}, {0.23493104304809412`, 
      0.4440809402390221`}}], 
   Line[{{0.23493104304809412`, 0.4440809402390221`}, {0.2255708635091629`, 
      0.4352755122957541`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2458063880151631`, 0.4529965121115738`}, {0.2362387193659058`, 
      0.44519046171637694`}}], 
   Line[{{0.24729866193283856`, 0.45414958092958785`}, {0.24648326240945`, 
      0.45363954361140574`}}], 
   Line[{{0.24648326240945`, 0.45363954361140574`}, {0.2458063880151631`, 
      0.4529965121115738`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2570213951396619`, 0.46095021578202966`}, {0.24729866193283856`, 
      0.45414958092958785`}}], 
   Line[{{0.25867545846199563`, 0.4621600936383677`}, {0.2577865151619174`, 
      0.4616258862109966`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2577865151619174`, 0.4616258862109966`}, {0.2570213951396619`, 
      0.46095021578202966`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2713565274343649`, 0.46964096460519306`}, {0.27029474445148616`, 
      0.46923832388523573`}}], 
   Line[{{0.27029474445148616`, 0.46923832388523573`}, {0.2693435427651083`, 
      0.4686736095095178`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2693435427651083`, 0.4686736095095178`}, {0.25867545846199563`, 
      0.4621600936383677`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2820834503649971`, 0.47540708814525406`}, {0.28108085796610294`, 
      0.4748070587399311`}}], 
   Line[{{0.28317996258778066`, 0.47583890202372664`}, {0.2820834503649971`, 
      0.47540708814525406`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2929264508462746`, 0.4800548651057634`}, {0.28317996258778066`, 
      0.47583890202372664`}}], 
   Line[{{0.28108085796610294`, 0.4748070587399311`}, {0.2713565274343649`, 
      0.46964096460519306`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2962869754197271`, 0.4814350589126312`}, {0.2950906392127613`, 
      0.48115832533184144`}}], 
   Line[{{0.293969971604404`, 0.48069317434650516`}, {0.2929264508462746`, 
      0.4800548651057634`}}], 
   Line[{{0.2950906392127613`, 0.48115832533184144`}, {0.293969971604404`, 
      0.48069317434650516`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3070188184813319`, 0.4856253611147443`}, {0.30588411540871324`, 
      0.4851249910683927`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3082111485742116`, 0.48593284952392213`}, {0.3070188184813319`, 
      0.4856253611147443`}}], 
   Line[{{0.30588411540871324`, 0.4851249910683927`}, {0.2962869754197271`, 
      0.4814350589126312`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3200745284695116`, 0.4896040338211999`}, {0.31889586095955874`, 
      0.4892654893053082`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3306538583299412`, 0.49210181021046007`}, {0.3200745284695116`, 
      0.4896040338211999`}}], 
   Line[{{0.31889586095955874`, 0.4892654893053082`}, {0.3082111485742116`, 
      0.48593284952392213`}}], 
   Line[{{0.32775672771374703`, 0.17512244347152398`}, {0.34339600647788815`, 
      0.19037157889533632`}}], 
   Line[{{0.34339600647788815`, 0.19037157889533632`}, {0.3584920715847559`, 
      0.20748513832003038`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3584920715847559`, 0.20748513832003038`}, {0.37529647269459104`, 
      0.22416045439778076`}}], 
   Line[{{0.391394006394934`, 0.24187639988977794`}, {0.40595760835145256`, 
      0.26052294423977673`}}], 
   Line[{{0.40595760835145256`, 0.26052294423977673`}, {0.4211937389690042`, 
      0.2783989008665915`}}], 
   Line[{{0.37529647269459104`, 0.22416045439778076`}, {0.391394006394934`, 
      0.24187639988977794`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4211937389690042`, 0.2783989008665915`}, {0.4360859857909327`, 
      0.29688362962532056`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4360859857909327`, 0.29688362962532056`}, {0.44849554349384785`, 
      0.31513488497582964`}}], 
   Line[{{0.44849554349384785`, 0.31513488497582964`}, {0.45950702525841847`, 
      0.3312352642133482`}}], 
   Line[{{0.45950702525841847`, 0.3312352642133482`}, {0.47168951000586257`, 
      0.3485013232084075`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3329811696167614`, 0.49261958674849604`}, {0.33180955627977493`, 
      0.49246904090890936`}}], 
   Line[{{0.33180955627977493`, 0.49246904090890936`}, {0.3306538583299412`, 
      0.49210181021046007`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3433488889598254`, 0.4945445748405384`}, {0.3329811696167614`, 
      0.49261958674849604`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3546249958718492`, 0.495842695338322`}, {0.3444697509923371`, 
      0.49471602188622743`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3444697509923371`, 0.49471602188622743`}, {0.3433488889598254`, 
      0.4945445748405384`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3556865540320001`, 0.4960280715277968`}, {0.3546249958718492`, 
      0.495842695338322`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3567177912758346`, 0.49597308113395`}, {0.3556865540320001`, 
      0.4960280715277968`}}], 
   Line[{{0.47168951000586257`, 0.3485013232084075`}, {0.48077950746507786`, 
      0.3644837993542871`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4860140377063631`, 0.37629909992727895`}, {0.494713514709459`, 
      0.3908117600585477`}}], 
   Line[{{0.48077950746507786`, 0.3644837993542871`}, {0.4860140377063631`, 
      0.37629909992727895`}}], 
   Line[{{0.494713514709459`, 0.3908117600585477`}, {0.5001882062215272`, 
      0.4033850666119429`}}], 
   Line[{{0.36750825194268794`, 0.4965078617110783`}, {0.36656376103364224`, 
      0.49656032955172325`}}], 
   Line[{{0.36656376103364224`, 0.49656032955172325`}, {0.3567177912758346`, 
      0.49597308113395`}}], 
   Line[{{0.37788302207581576`, 0.4962518669896069`}, {0.37703288668338875`, 
      0.4963125224987447`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3870248630651093`, 0.4952799609069687`}, {0.37788302207581576`, 
      0.4962518669896069`}}], 
   Line[{{0.37703288668338875`, 0.4963125224987447`}, {0.36750825194268794`, 
      0.4965078617110783`}}], 
   Line[{{0.3877734346697613`, 0.49519893336654924`}, {0.3870248630651093`, 
      0.4952799609069687`}}], 
   Line[{{0.39647039041779775`, 0.49345442085222035`}, {0.3877734346697613`, 
      0.49519893336654924`}}], 
   Line[{{0.397110731984245`, 0.4933399169989696`}, {0.39647039041779775`, 
      0.49345442085222035`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4053005892876792`, 0.4908254279842213`}, {0.397110731984245`, 
      0.4933399169989696`}}], 
   Line[{{0.40582676815159685`, 0.49066402514110335`}, {0.4053005892876792`, 
      0.4908254279842213`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4134479680115215`, 0.48738189051877207`}, {0.40582676815159685`, 
      0.49066402514110335`}}], 
   Line[{{0.41385501671116315`, 0.4871604717762271`}, {0.4134479680115215`, 
      0.48738189051877207`}}], 
   Line[{{0.5001882062215272`, 0.4033850666119429`}, {0.5026656466799566`, 
      0.41378366311013043`}}], 
   Line[{{0.5049910805017521`, 0.42092707055693956`}, {0.5073345408466324`, 
      0.4298919589211338`}}], 
   Line[{{0.5026656466799566`, 0.41378366311013043`}, {0.5049910805017521`, 
      0.42092707055693956`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4274391169072527`, 0.47801529681458305`}, {0.42084769258955246`, 
      0.48311400029769436`}}], 
   Line[{{0.42084769258955246`, 0.48311400029769436`}, {0.41385501671116315`, 
      0.4871604717762271`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4329580876836497`, 0.47231834863067207`}, {0.4274391169072527`, 
      0.47801529681458305`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4331675034193015`, 0.4720847717913544`}, {0.4329580876836497`, 
      0.47231834863067207`}}], 
   Line[{{0.437890159746943`, 0.46566606263920335`}, {0.4331675034193015`, 
      0.4720847717913544`}}], 
   Line[{{0.5073345408466324`, 0.4298919589211338`}, {0.507075192557166`, 
      0.43670292340445127`}}], 
   Line[{{0.507075192557166`, 0.43670292340445127`}, {0.5049458541122729`, 
      0.4449675445229827`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4776009750118953`, 0.4514099006447918`}, {0.4730868229244228`, 
      0.45077008810913194`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4730868229244228`, 0.45077008810913194`}, {0.437890159746943`, 
      0.46566606263920335`}}], 
   Line[{{0.5049458541122729`, 0.4449675445229827`}, {0.5029083407423581`, 
      0.44889688974935993`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4838758910848437`, 0.45289412540402957`}, {0.4776009750118953`, 
      0.4514099006447918`}}], 
   Line[{{0.5029083407423581`, 0.44889688974935993`}, {0.49919310111973014`, 
      0.45113398227358853`}}], 
   Line[{{0.4890646389147416`, 0.45348782067176335`}, {0.4838758910848437`, 
      0.45289412540402957`}}], 
   Line[{{0.49919310111973014`, 0.45113398227358853`}, {0.49332267538788155`, 
      0.45296691617990653`}}], 
   Line[{{0.49332267538788155`, 0.45296691617990653`}, {0.4890646389147416`, 
      0.45348782067176335`}}]};
```

Convert lines to points

```
pts = Flatten[linelist1 /. Line -> Identity, {2}][[1]];
```

Using [`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html)

```
ListCurvePathPlot[pts,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Using [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html)

```
curve = FindCurvePath[pts];

ListLinePlot[pts[[curve[[1]]]],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> Dashed,
 ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

Comment: You coded  `Flatten`  with the optional second argument between curly braces. Where is this use documented?  In the documenation for `Flatten` I have access to this argument is without braces. Thanks

Comment: @SigisK - See the tutorial [Levels in Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DiscretizeGraphics` for this:

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[linelist1]
```

and if you want a graphics out of it:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[mr], {Dashed, 
   MeshCells[mr, {1, All}, Multicells -> True]}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the dashing problem still fails with this. Try `Dashing[.01]` and you'll see that it still does it unevenly.

Answer (score 3):

```
sTour = FindShortestTour[data = Flatten[First /@ linelist1, 1]];
Graphics[{Dashing[0.01], Line[data[[sTour [[2]]]]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about literal replacing lines with dashed lines?

```
Graphics@linelist1 /. Line[a_] -> {Dashed, Line[a]}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for me this produces the uneven dashing in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, which doesn't rely on any fancy functions:

```
appendNextSegment[{acc_, rest_}] := Module[{closeness, nearest, pos, next},
  closeness = Map[Norm[(Last@acc) - First@#] &, rest];
  nearest = Min[closeness];
  pos = Position[closeness, nearest][[1, 1]];
  next = rest[[pos]];
  Return[{acc~Join~next, Delete[rest, pos]}]
  ]
lineJoin[listOfLines_] := Line[Nest[
    appendNextSegment, 
    ({First@listOfLines, Rest@listOfLines} /. Line -> Sequence),
    Length[listOfLines] - 1][[1]]
    ]
```

Then

```
Graphics@{Dashed, lineJoin@linelist1}
Graphics@{Dashed, lineJoin@linelist2}
```

produce nice graphics (that I can't paste here, as imgur is blocked at work).

Comment: Wait, what qualifies a function as "fancy"?  :-P

Comment: My working definition is that a function is fancy if you can't immediately understand by looking at its name what inputs you should pass it or what the output ought to be.