# Find path through a set of Coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of coordinates that I need a robot to draw, thus it must take the shortest path along these coordinates. Plotting them looks like this:

```
Graphics[Point[maskCoordinates]]
```

[image: Plot of Path]

**EDIT:** `maskCoordinates` is derived from the following code, which runs `EdgeDetect` and `ComponentMeasurements` on any given image, and for this example works with the first mask:

```
intWidth = 100;
imgCar = Import["https://2hire.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/car.png"];
imgCar = ColorConvert[imgCar, "Grayscale"];
imgCar = ImageResize[imgCar, intWidth];

edges = Thinning@EdgeDetect@imgCar;
masks = ComponentMeasurements[edges, "Mask"];
maskCoordinates = PixelValuePositions[Image@masks[[1, 2]], 1];
```

I have tried using `FindShortestTour`, but that only works for "complete" shapes/masks that I'm working with, like a circle. So applying this to the given mask, I get:

```
Graphics[Line[maskCoordinates[[Last[FindShortestTour[maskCoordinates]]]]]]
```

[image: Plotted Path 2]

Which is close, but not exactly what I want. I thought that `FindShortestPath` would get the job done, but haven't had any succes with that yet.

Comment: Please add the information of `maskCoordinates`.

Comment: Have you tried `FindCurvePath`?

Comment: @AnjanKumar Heh, fixed!

Comment: Aren't you looking for the `Nearest` local point at each step, rather than the global shortest path?

Comment: @Androvich Your code for `maskCoordinates` doesn't work with the first image from the question. Please provide the explicit set of points or the original image `imgCar` to which the code should be applied.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov oh yes, of course... It's added now, my bad!

Answer (score 7):

[`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot) is pretty close:

```
ListCurvePathPlot[maskCoordinates]
```

[image]

**FindShortestTour**

You can get your [`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour) method to work if you give [`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour) a good starting and ending point. For instance, we can find the left-most and right-most points using [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering):

```
left = First @ Ordering[maskCoordinates, 1]
right = First @ Ordering[maskCoordinates, -1]
```

> 110
>
> 115

Feed these to [`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour):

```
tour = FindShortestTour[maskCoordinates, left, right][[2]];
```

Plot the tour:

```
Graphics[{Line[maskCoordinates[[tour]]]}]
```

[image]

**Update to add comparisons**
I think the [`NearestNeighborGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph) and [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath) approaches won't work well when the path has a near intersection that is smaller than the distance between points on the path. To show this, here is a comparison of the three current answers on such a set of points:

```
pts = Join[{
    {.2,-.998027},{.4,-.998026}},
    N @ CirclePoints[{0,0},1,50],
    {{-.2,-.998027}, {-.4,-.998027}
}];
Graphics @ Point @ pts
```

[image]

Here is the result using [`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour) (starting and ending points are needed for this approach):

```
Graphics[{
    Line @ pts[[Last @ FindShortestTour[pts, 2, 54]]],
    Point @ pts
}]
```

[image]

Here is the result using [`NearestNeighborGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph):

```
Graphics[{
    Line @ FindHamiltonianPath @ NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 2],
    Point[pts]
}]
```

[image]

The approach using [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath) suggested by @AlexeyPopkov didn't work for this set of points.

Comment: ListCurvePathPlot seems quite good, but how do I get the array of coordinates as a list?

I also think that FindShortestTour might be the best option here, where I tried it with Last & First, I didn't think about using Ordering. I'll have to experiment with this as soon as I get access to the robot again - thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, will the ordering method work with a path like [this](https://imgur.com/Kf8gR06) ?

Answer (score 7):

```
Graphics @ Line @ FindHamiltonianPath @ NearestNeighborGraph[maskCoordinates, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: I think [`NearestNeighborGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph) will not work when the path has near intersections that are smaller than the distance between points. For example, try your method with ``pts=Join[{{.2,-.998027},{.4,-.998026}},N @ CirclePoints[{0,0},1,50],{{-.2,-.998027},{-.4,-.998027}}]``.

Comment: @CarlWoll I agree, but can that occur when the points are pixel positions from an image edge component ?

Comment: Since we have 8-connectivity in the original pixels, we can utilize this fact by providing radius `Sqrt[2]`: `NearestNeighborGraph[maskCoordinates, {2, Sqrt[2]}]`.

Comment: Neat! I'm going to try this out as soon as I get access to the robot and see what works the best, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Using a "fix" for `FindCurvePath` by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95550/280) (please read the original answer):

```
segments = FindCurvePath@maskCoordinates;
edges = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ segments;
edges = Join @@ edges;

g = Graph@edges;
path = FindShortestPath[g, ##] & @@ 
  Flatten[Position[VertexDegree[g], 1]];

Graphics[Line[maskCoordinates[[path]]]]
```

> [image: plot]

Looks good at first sight, but some points aren't included:

```
maskCoordinates // Length
path // Length
ListPlot[maskCoordinates[[#]] & /@ segments]
```

> ```
> 149
> 142
> ```
>
> [image: plot]

---

Some other techniques can be found in answers to the following questions:

- [How to group and join points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105988/280)
- [Finding a function that fits the shape of an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75855/280)
- [Parametric Interpolation of 2D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47332/280)
- [How to connect discrete points and make them become continuous curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70102/280)
- [How to create a new "person curve"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17704/280)
- [How can I combine a list of Line[]'s into one continuous Line?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120285/280)
- [Can I get the curvature at any point of a random curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95425/280)

... and in the following answers:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102633/280
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/639/280

Comment: An interesting approach indeed, going to try it! I think that FindShortestTour with give start and end coordinates might work well, but I'm going to try all the different methods and see what works best, thank you.